# <input type="hidden"> working fine in Firefox, but not in Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, input

I'm pretty new to all this so forgive me if this is a stupid question! I have some JavaScript that converts centimetres to inches, centimetres to meters, meters to inches etc. when the  user clicks the relevant button. I want to hide buttons that are not relevant. i.e. When the user selects the input unit to inches, the 'centimetres to inches' is irrelevant and should be hidden.

The code I have works fine in Firefox and only half works in chrome. As the user selects the unit from a drop down it should show/hide the buttons as appropriate. But in Chrome it only works the first time you select a unit, and does not update when a different unit is selected.

Here's the HTML:

```
            <select id="unit" onchange="TriangleArea()" class="unitOut">
                <option value="" id="unitCSS" onClick="CreateButtons()">Select Unit...</option>
                <option value="CM" onClick="CreateButtons()">Centimeters</option>
                <option value="M" onClick="CreateButtons()">Meters</option>
                <option value="Inch" onClick="CreateButtons()">Inches</option>
            </select>
```

And here's the JavaScript:

```
function CreateButtons(){
        if (unit == "CM" )
        {
            document.getElementById("button1").setAttribute("type", "button"); // shows button1 (CM to Inch)
            document.getElementById("button2").setAttribute("type", "hidden"); // hides button2 (Inch to CM)
            document.getElementById("button3").setAttribute("type", "button"); // shows button3 (CM to M)
            document.getElementById("button4").setAttribute("type", "hidden"); // hides button4 (M to CM)
            document.getElementById("3cube").style.visibility="visible";
        }
        else if (unit =="Inch")
        {
            document.getElementById("button1").setAttribute("type", "hidden"); 
            document.getElementById("button2").setAttribute("type", "button"); 
            document.getElementById("button3").setAttribute("type", "hidden"); 
            document.getElementById("button4").setAttribute("type", "hidden");
            document.getElementById("3cube").style.visibility="visible";
        }
        else if (unit =="M")
        {
            document.getElementById("button1").setAttribute("type", "hidden"); 
            document.getElementById("button2").setAttribute("type", "hidden"); 
            document.getElementById("button3").setAttribute("type", "hidden"); 
            document.getElementById("button4").setAttribute("type", "button");
            document.getElementById("3cube").style.visibility="visible";
        }           
        else if (unit =="")
        {
            document.getElementById("button1").setAttribute("type", "button"); 
            document.getElementById("button2").setAttribute("type", "button"); 
            document.getElementById("button3").setAttribute("type", "button"); 
            document.getElementById("button4").setAttribute("type", "button");  
            document.getElementById("3cube").style.visibility="hidden";
        }
    }
```

The `unit` variable is declared with global scope in the body of the document. It is set to the value of `<select id="unit">` with the code `unit = document.getElementById("unit").value` and it is working correctly. So why does Firefox hide/show the buttons every time the user changes the option for the unit but Chrome will only show the correct buttons the first time and not update when the unit is changed?

Solved! `onchange="CreateButtons()"` needed to be an attribute of `<select>`, not `<option>`. Thanks for all your time and help!

Comment: Sorry I should have clarified that. The `unit` variable is set to the value of the selected `<option>` ie either nothing, CM, M or Inch. Using the code `unit = document.getElementById("unit").value`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use style -> `display` property to hide and show the buttons. Do not make them hidden. Like,

```
document.getElementById("button1").style.display='none'; // hides button1
document.getElementById("button1").style.display='block'; // shows button1
```

`display:none` also hides the space occupied by the button.

And do not use 'onclick' for each option,

```
            <select id="unit" onchange="CreateButtons()" class="unitOut">
                <option value="" id="unitCSS">Select Unit...</option>
                <option value="CM">Centimeters</option>
                <option value="M">Meters</option>
                <option value="Inch">Inches</option>
            </select>
```

Assign the 'unit' variable like this,

```
function CreateButtons(){
        var unit = document.getElementById('unit').value;
        // do your rest of the code ...
        if (unit == "CM" )
        {
           // your code ...
        }
}
```

Hope it works, let me know if you want more help. Thanks.

Comment: I tied this but it still didn't work 
`   if (unit == "CM" )
   {
    document.getElementById("button1").style.display='block'; // shows button1 (CM to Inch)
    document.getElementById("button2").style.display='none'; // hides button2 (Inch to CM)
        document.getElementById("button4").style.display='none'; // hides button4 (M to CM)
    
   }`

And this HTML:

`<button id="button1" style="display: none;" onClick="CentiToInch()">CM to Inch</button>`

Comment: It is very basic javascript and it should work in Chrome. Please check if javascript is enabled in your Google Chrome once. Please see the edited answer.

Comment: Yes, JavaScript is enabled. Don't worry about it, it's not important work! Thanks for your help!

Comment: Yes, because you have not assigned 'unit' variable which you are using in conditions. Please check edited answer.

Comment: I added the line you suggested to set the 'unit' variable to the value of the `<select id="unit">` and put an alert for 'unit'. It only alerts the first time and not subsequent times which would suggest selecting an option is not running the CreateButtons() function. Interestingly a previous change has now 'broken' it in Firefox so that Firefox and Chrome are now behaving the same way.

Comment: Sorry, call `CreateButtons()` function on change event. And what are you doing in `TriangleArea()` function?

Comment: I figured it out! `onchange="CreateButtons()"` needed to be an attribute of `<select>`, not `<option>`. Thanks for your time and help!

Comment: Yes, that means you did not check my edited answer :)

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to show and hide the buttons just like you're making "3cube" visible i.e.

Hide Button:

```
document.getElementById('button1').style.visibility = 'hidden';
```

Show Button:

```
document.getElementById('button1').style.visibility = 'visible';
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using the 'Style.Visibility' attribute, I suggest you to use
'Style.display' attribute to hide/display buttons as mentioned by @balaG previously.

This is because, the button once you set as,

```
Style.Visibility=false;
```

you will not be able to find it again in DOM by using,

```
document.getElementByID('some_id');
```

Hope this helps!!

Comment: @Luves2spooge : May be the case is like, The 'unit' that you are comparing with values like CM,Inch etc is not working for you.

Comment: Try to find the selected value out of dropdown. i.e., use like If($('#unit').val()=="CM") in if else ladder in your function 'CreateButtons()' Try to alert both unit and $('#unit').val() in your function 'CreateButtons()'  and see weather you are getting desired values in that

Answer (score 0):

`<option onclick=>` doesn't work on Chrome.  You should listen to 'change' event of the `<select>` element.

Comment: I tried changing it to `onchange` but this didn't fix it either. Thanks though!